# how to know if i should use redux for my application or any other alternative?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to react native and mobile development world.
I am developing a mobile application with react native, it's basically an entreprise management app for HR management, storage management, projects and tasks management, clients management, and it contains user authentification with different roles.

The backend and database are already developed.
What are my options to handle data and what are the difference between them ?

I did researches and i am wondering if i should use redux in this application or is there any other alternatives because apparently redux is very hard and i only have 2 months to finish the project

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR You are alone and you have 2 months, go with what you know*.

*In rare cases described below go with Redux.

### It very much depends on several points:

#### Expected live of the app

If you expect the app to be done in 2 months and to never ever look at it again, then Redux or basically any other architecture pattern/library will be mostly a drag, especially for your case as you are a single developer on this project (from what I understand). Architecture is an investment, and from the kind that does not pay back in 2 man/months, maybe in a few man/years.
As you are alone and the deadline is near I would advise you to just go with what you know*. From personal experience in a team of ~20 developers on >250K LOC codebase with very complex state management, we started to see the benefits >5 months after the initial introduction of Redux in the app.

*Except in the cases described below...

#### BE responses caching and depth of components

Redux solves response caching and props drilling problems (and others but these you might experience the most). In case you have to cache data from the BE while changing screens Redux can help there. As for boilerplate if you use RTK (Redux toolkit: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) you will write a bit more than without Redux, for the same caching. If you will have a very deep component tree then Redux will simply remove the passing of props and callbacks down the tree, you will use selectors and actions instead which are not passed but just included in the component.

So if there is a big need for caching and/or there will be a lot of props drilling Redux might just pay off in that 2 months (not a high chance but maybe).

#### Complex state, Complex BE requests, complex error handling

By complex state, I mean something that has at least several states (ex: connected, disconnected, retrying, offline, permission problem, etc.) and non-trivial logic for transition between these states. For example you need to start some user interaction for permissions and the continue from where you left off.

By complex requests I mean at least several endpoints with retries required and maybe passing data from the response of one request to the input of the next. In this case, the state management will be hard and Redux might be a good solution for that. Also, error handling where you do not want to just show an error toast, but to retry on user request or similar might also be a point for Redux (I would not consider error handling alone as enough for going to Redux).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend mobx.
It uses dark magic and can be hard to debug, but it works well most of the time.

Redux is not hard. The concept is rather easy, but it requires too much boilerplate IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

From: Mateusz Grzesiukiewicz Book “Hands-On Design Patterns with
React Native” :

**Comparing Redux and MobX**

This section is highly influenced by Preethi Kasireddy's talk at React Conf
2017. Please spend half an hour and watch it. You can find the talk
at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76FRrbY18Bs.

- **Redux** uses plain objects, while **MobX** wraps objects into **Observables**.
  You may expect me to mention some magic again—no. The brutal truth is that
  **MobX** comes at a cost. It needs to wrap **observable** data and add some weight to
  each single object or each member of a collection. It is fairly easy to look up just
  how much data: use console.log to see your observable collection.
- **Redux** manually tracks updates, whereas **MobX** automatically tracks updates.
- A **Redux** state is read-only and can be altered by dispatching an action, while a
  **MobX** state can be altered at any time, sometimes only by using actions exposed
  by your Store API. Also, in **MobX**, actions are not required. You can change state
  directly.
- In **Redux**, a state is typically normalized, or at least this is recommended. In
  **MobX**, your state is denormalized and computed values are nested.
- **Stateless and stateful components**: here it may seem difficult. Preethi Kasireddy,
  in the lecture linked in the preceding information box, mentioned that **MobX** can
  be used with smart components only. To some extent, this is true, but there is no
  distinction here from **Redux**. Both support presentational components, as these
  are completely decoupled from state management libraries!
- The learning curve—this is very subjective criteria. Some will find **Redux** easier,
  others will find **MobX** easier. The popular belief is that **MobX** is easier to learn.
  I'm an exception to this.
- **Redux** requires more boilerplate. Being more explicit, this is quite
  straightforward, but there are libraries that fix this if you don't care. No
  references will be provided here, as I recommend educated use.
- **Redux** is much easier to debug. This comes naturally with single flow and easy
  replay of messages. This is where **Redux** shines. **MobX** is more old-school here, a
  little harder to predict, and not so obvious, even to experienced users.
- **Redux** wins when it comes to scalability. **MobX** may pose some maintainability
  problems, especially in big projects with a lot of connections and a big domain.
- **MobX** is concise and shines in small, time-constrained projects. If you go to a
  hackathon, consider using **MobX**. In big, long-term projects, you would need a
  more opinionated approach on top of the freedom that **MobX** gives.
- **MobX** follows the **Flux architecture** and does not alter it as much as **Redux** does.
- **Redux** leans towards one global store (although can be used with many!), while
  **MobX** is quite flexible with the amount of stores and its examples usually
  demonstrate similar thinking to the early ideas of **Flux**.

While using **Redux**, you need to learn how to deal with different situations and how to
structure things. When it comes to dealing with side effects especially, you will need to
learn **Redux** **Thunk** and possibly **Redux Saga**, which will be introduced in the following
chapter. In **MobX**, all of this is magically taken care of behind the scenes, using reactive
streams. In this respect, **MobX** is opinionated, but takes one responsibility away from you.

While using **Redux**, you need to learn how to deal with different situations and how to
structure things. When it comes to dealing with side effects especially, you will need to
learn **Redux Thunk** and possibly Redux Saga. In **MobX**, all of this is magically taken care of behind the scenes, using reactive
streams. In this respect, **MobX** is opinionated, but takes one responsibility away from you.

**MobX** is like system of roads for cars. You create a road map and let people drive. Some
will cause accidents, some will drive carefully. Some roads may be limited to one-way to
restrict traffic a little, or even shaped in a certain way to allow easier reasoning about the
car flow, as in Manhattan. **Redux**, on the other hand, is like a train. Only one train can move
on a track at a time. If there are a few at the same moment and something is holding up the
one in front, every other train waits behind, just like in a subway station. Sometimes trains
need to transfer people as far as the other side of a continent, and this is also possible. All of
this train flow is governed by one (distributed) agency that plans the movement and puts
restrictions on the train flow.